# Where does Visual Studio put ASP.NET When it's Compiled/Running

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, runtime, iis-express

I'm trying to find the location Visual Studio puts ASP.NET applications when they're compiled and running.  I ask because when I run my project from VS it's running an old branch I was looking at yesterday instead of the branch I have open in VS to work on (which is updated).  I remember finding the location before and deleting these files causing VS to re-make (or recompile?) them.  So where is the compiled code kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They go here:

**%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET Files**

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx)

Comment: And then obviously delete the folders within Temporary ASP.NET Files folder, yeah?